# Error validating the file spring-ldap.xsd

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

i have this error in my bean configuration, but for another project works.. the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">
```

but in one project i have this error:

```
referenced file contains error http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE:

i modify my beam like this and work (i added conf. for pooling but is not important):

```
<!-- LDAP config -->

    <bean id="contextSourceTarget" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
        <property name="pooled" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSourceTarget" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked to fix the problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526687/spring-security-ldap-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-ldap-authenticati for me

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because Pivotal's site is displaying captcha before showing the actual XSD,

see [Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)
[image: Pivotal site requires captcha]

It depends on whether you get the error in the IDE or in the runtime.

If it's a specialized XML editor you should refer to the documentation of your editor on how to override/specify schema location, if it's in the runtime likely you have to check your project dependencies(pom.xml if it's a maven project).

Comment: i have the error in the IDE, if i try to run the project it works. I can ignore it?

Comment: what's your IDE? I would check first that it works without internet connection i.e. schamas are fetched corretly from jars.

Comment: i use Eclipse for IDE

Comment: I think you  can install that scheme into Eclipse manually https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog  Associate `http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd` with a physical file.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses its own mechanism to get the XSD in classpath library (runtime).

Uses following files

1. `META-INF/spring.handlers` (to parse tag xml to object by an Handler)

**example of spring-core-3.2.2.jar**

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler

2. `META-INF/spring.schemas` (to identify the correct xsd used)

**example of spring-core-3.2.2.jar**

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd

The IDE want resolve the location of the XSD by schemaLocation, for this reason I suggest to remove XSD validation on your Eclipse.

Windows->Preferences->Validation-> "Suspend all validators"

Comment: Windows->Preferences->Validation-> "Suspend all validators" no work for me

Comment: This practice remove all action of eclipse to perform validation, else in background try to find all resources (XSD). Anyway have you [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11429419/3364187).