# Spring Ldap unbind with tls connection. Authentication failure

Tags: ssl, unbind, spring-ldap

I'm using Spring Ldap to interact with my openLdap server which needs tls authentication. In order to authenticate I had to set the contextSource like:

```
TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy ctx = (TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy) ldapTemplate.getContextSource();
SecureLdapContextSource secureContextSource = new SecureLdapContextSource();
secureContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
ldapTemplate.setContextSource(secureContextSource);
```

Where is SecureLdapContextSource

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    //http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/33910-ldaps-external-certificate-contains-unsupported-critical-extensions-2-5-29-17
    this.setUrl("ldaps://myLdapServer.com:636/");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
    Hashtable<String, Object> envProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

    envProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    envProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://myLdapServer.com:636/");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "adminUsername");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "adminPwd");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    envProps.put("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
    envProps.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
    envProps.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "org.springframework.ldap.samples.useradmin.EmblSSLSocketFactory");
    System.setProperty("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "org.springframework.ldap.samples.useradmin.EmblSSLSocketFactory");

    //set the environment
    super.setupAuthenticatedEnvironment(envProps, keyStore, keyStorePassword);
    // set the base environment again
    super.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(envProps);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
    // it is necessary to call super.afterPropertiesSet() again!!!
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

After that I've been able to authenticate the admin with such call:

```
ldapTemplate.authenticate(queryAdmin, password);
```

After that comes my problem. I want to delete a user from the ldap with the unbind method:
ldapTemplate.unbind("dnOfMyWorsteColeague");

Running it on a test I get the following exception from the ldap server:
[LDAP: error code 8 - modifications require authentication]

So, I cannot (as I'm doing with my old ldap interface, w/o Spring Ldap) do an authentication and keep the session to execute commands that only the admin is allowed to do.

Any idea? I'd like to use Spring Ldap for that...

Thanks for any help, 
 Marco

Comment: do not use the beans.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by beans.xml?

Comment: i mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700291/error-validating-the-file-spring-ldap-xsd/26821202#26821202

Comment: Ok, I see Antonio. However, regardless the way in which the beans are wired together, I'm still not able to operate on the Ldap doing certain operations where Admin Rights are needed. Using Spring-Ldap.

Comment: Hi, i try your code, but for me tell me EmblSSLSocketFactory not found..sure it exsist?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this Q is super old, and I'm relatively new to LDAP but I think `unbind()` is used to close an LDAP connection, not delete a user.  To do that, you would use `delete()`

https://www.ldap.com/the-ldap-delete-operation